# Laravel 8: Undefined index

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, undefined-index

I'm working on a questionnaire project and I ran into an error saying:

> Undefined index: exams

This happened when I was trying to store responses to my database.

Here is my controller code:

```
    public function store(Math $math)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'responses.*.answer_id' => 'required',
            'responses.*.question_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        $exam = $math->exams()->create($data['exams']);
        $exam->examanswers()->createMany($data['examanswers']);

        return 'Thank You';
    }
```

Here is my exam model:

```
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['exam'];

    public function math()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Math::class);
    }

    public function examanswers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ExamAnswer::class);
    }
}
```

question model:

```
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['question'];

    public function math()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Math::class);
    }

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}
```

Math model:

```
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'title', 'purpose', 'exam'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }

    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Exam::class);
    }
}
```

Please help me look into it.

Comment: why should `$data['exams']` exists?

Comment: Just see on your validation rules.. i did not see “exams” there.

Comment: @Maksim I was actually following my tutor, it's the project after  course and there was no validation for exams but trying it now removed the error

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia : It exist because I'm trying to save users responses

Comment: Why u dont ask tutor?

Answer (score 1):

`request()->validate(RULES)` will return an array with all the existing `rules' indexes`. It will not return all data present, just what it is in the rules and present.

Read how [`$request->validate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) works.

For example:

If you send `home = 'Address'`, `name = 'John'` and `email = 123`, but your rules are:

```php
$data = $request->validate([
    'home' => 'required',
    'name' => 'required',
]);
```

Then, if you want to use `$data` you would have (`dd($data)`):

- `$data['home']`: `Address`
- `$data['name']`: `John`

But `email = 123` would not be present in `$data`.